# executing commands from a java file

Tags: java, console

```
import java.io.*;

public class chk 
{
String className;
String command,command1,command2;
public String  getMsg(String fileName,String Path) 
{
    String dir;
    command1="cd "+Path;
    dir=Path.charAt(0)+Path.charAt(1)+"";
    command2=dir;
command = "javac " + fileName;
    String a=executeCommand(command1);
    a=executeCommand(command2);
String output = executeCommand(command);
if(output.compareTo("")==0)             
        output = "Compilation Successfull!!";
    return output;
}
private String executeCommand(String command) 
{
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    Process p;
    try 
    {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader1.readLine())!= null) 
        {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        while ((line = reader2.readLine())!= null) 
        {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output.toString();
}
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
        String x;
    chk ob=new chk();
    x=ob.getMsg("MyClass.java","D:\test");
    System.out.println("OUtput : "+x);
}
}
```

Error

[image]

I am trying to run a bunch of commands in command prompt with the help of a java file so that later i can compile another java file named "MyClass.java" which is present at some other drive in my computer but i am getting the following error stating it cannot even execute my first command i.e "command1="cd "+Path;" this line . pls help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd` is not a program on Windows.  If you open a Command Prompt window, this runs a program `cmd.exe` that inputs and handles the commands.  Many commands will cause programs to be executed, but some commands are interpreted by `cmd.exe` itself, including the `cd` command.  And the `cd` command will set up some state in the Command Prompt window that will affect how the same `cmd.exe` handles future commands.  Because of this, not only can you not run `cd` as a program, you also cannot run `cmd.exe` and use it to process a `cd` command.  You *could*, but it won't do you any good, because the `cd` command will only affect what goes on inside that `cmd.exe` process, and then `cmd.exe` will terminate.

You probably want to look into `ProcessBuilder`, which has a method `directory` to set the working directory of the process.  (I'm not real familiar with this class, so I can't give you any specific examples.  But it does look like it's what you need.)

**EDIT:** After looking into this further: You're using the `exec` method of `Runtime`.  The `exec` method has a version that takes the working directory as a parameter:

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
```

So if you use this with `null` for `envp` (assuming you don't want to create a new set of environment variables), and with a `File` set up to refer to the working directory, I think this will give you what you want.  So you may be able to do things this way instead of using `ProcessBuilder`.

**MORE:** For a command like

```
java zzzzzz < C:\iptest\input.txt > C:\outtest\name.txt
```

When you type this command in a Command Prompt window, the `cmd.exe` program interprets the `<` and `>` commands to redirect input and output, and takes care of the needed actions.  They won't work in a command executed by `exec()` because they'll just be treated as command-line arguments.  The `exec` method of `Runtime` doesn't have a mechanism for setting up redirected input and output files, but `ProcessBuilder` does.  See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  I don't have much experience with `ProcessBuilder`, but it looks like you need to create a `ProcessBuilder` object, use `command` to set up the command and arguments (as separate strings, not as one long string with space characters), use `directory` to set the working directory, use `redirectInput` and `redirectOutput` to set up the files for redirection, and then `start()`.

Comment: what i will give in place of 3rd parameter ?

Comment: i have a path i.e "D:\test" how to cast it into a file ?

Comment: `new File("D:\\test")`.  This is in the documentation for the `File` class.

Comment: how to compile "command ="java " + name +" < C:\\iptest\\input.txt > C:\\outtest\\"+name+".txt";" in the same way

Comment: see my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785626/executing-a-class-from-a-java-file-with-java-commands-in-it)

Comment: sorry to bother you again the previous java command problem is solved but now when i am compiling with "sum.exe < C:\iptest\input.txt > C:\outtest\sum.txt" this command. The output file gets generated with nothing stored in it i.e a 0KB file is formed . Pls HELP! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802736/executing-c-command-from-a-java-file?noredirect=1#comment32991835_21802736)